# Getting a 404 error calling to my managed package's custom rest endpoint in Sandbox

Tags: apex, managed-package

When someone installs our managed package we kick off an API call to a custom rest endpoint contained in the package like so:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Authorization:Bearer token' 
https://customnamespace.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/MyNameSpace/customendpoint -d 
'{"testfield1":"testing","testfield2":"testing","testfield3":"testing"}'
```

This has worked for us several times in different organization installs. However, just recently we had a customer install the package and get an error. After looking in the logs I see we're getting a 404 response when making the above request. Why would this be happening in just *one* organization but not any of the others?

**Update: I realized this is happening in a Sandbox org only. When I log in via the UI the url looks like this:

https://mycustomnamespace--testsf--mycustomnamespace.cs43.visual.force.com

But in my OAuth call the "instance" url I get back looks like this:

https://mycustomnamespace.my.salesforce.com/

Any idea how I can change the url to make a proper auth call against a Sandbox? And how to detect when this is necessary?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think providing an answer for this question, given the limited information is going to be extremely difficult. Especially since you state this code works for all orgs but one. That means that there is something specific with that org that could be preventing you from accessing it. Does the user that is authorizing in the token have API access? Could the token have expired? Thats where I would start looking. Seems like an access issue give the scenario.

Comment: I have new information - I will update the original question